# How to declare variable that has a struct array outside function

Tags: ios, swift

I need to use the currentQuestion variable outside of the randomQuestionGenerator function. Whats the proper syntax for declaring it beforehand?

```
struct Questions {
    var Question: String
    var answer: Int
    var answers: [String]
}

class GameScreen: UIViewController {

var correctAnswer = 0
var fullQuestions: [Questions] = []

func RandomQuestionGenerator(){
    let randomQuestion = 
Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(fullQuestions.count)))
    var currentQuestion = fullQuestions[randomQuestion]
    correctAnswer = currentQuestion.answer
```

Comment: Why don't you make your `currentQuestion` similar to `correctAnswer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `currentQuestion` as an optional outside the function:

```
var currentQuestion : Questions? = nil
func RandomQuestionGenerator() {
    let randomQuestion = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(fullQuestions.count)))
    currentQuestion = fullQuestions[randomQuestion]
    correctAnswer = currentQuestion.answer
}
```

Although you could do that, a better approach is to make your function *return* the random question, like this:

```
func RandomQuestionGenerator() -> Questions {
    let randomQuestion = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(fullQuestions.count)))
    return fullQuestions[randomQuestion]
}
```

Now you can use the function to retrieve the next random question, and get its fields as needed:

```
let nextQuestion = RandomQuestionGenerator()
print(nextQuestion.Question)
print(nextQuestion.answers)
```

Comment: The function has a lot more to it aside from just setting up a random question variable, I cut it out to keep it simple.

Comment: Also when I try to declare it as type of questions, my view controller says it has no initializers and doesn't run, why is this?

Comment: @RichardParker It needs to be optional, too, so that an unassigned state would be allowed.